# Why fs.readFile is not a function when run tests in karma and jasmine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a function that must find a file(.zip) and return it, that i can use it as argument for another function. Also I have test in karma/jasmine where i lunch my search function and when I do this its throws an error that [**'fs.readFile is not a function'**](https://prnt.sc/k1vz3i)
test code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const JSZip = require("jszip");

const searchfile = () => {


fs.readFile('./data/2-11253540.zip', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(function (zip) {
        console.log('Process Zip: ', zip);
    });
});
};

describe('Process', () => {

const process = require('./process');
searchfile();
it('001', () => expect(process()).toEqual(null));

});
```

it's looks not very similar to what I described above, but it was a test version to check if it work or not. In my karma config I have browserify to handle require.

So, **searchfile** function search a file and **process** function will use this file. When I run this test I have error that **fs.readFile is not a function**.
However if I put a code of **searchfile** in **process** function and run it directly it work fine.

Why it's not work ?

Comment: I was trying to use [browserify-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify-fs) , but it's not helped.

Comment: Moved to Mocha, works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the last couple of lines of green text in the screenshot (why are you posting PICTURES of text?!).

You are running the tests in Chrome.

The fs module is a Node.js feature.

The fs module is not available in Chrome (and it would be silly if a web page could read arbitrary files from the visitor’s file system).

Comment: Ok, thanks, but how should i rewrite my test config and/or test, to make it work ? Using PhantomJS ?

Comment: PhantomJS also runs code in a browser. If you want to test things for Node.js, then you need a test runner which is designed to run the tests using Node.js and not using a browser.